Flink java 17 compatibility failing for flink jobs
I am writing flink jobs with latest flink version 1.18.1 (tried with latest beta version). The flink jobmanager builds also support java 17. But the flink libraries for writing the jobs, especially flink-core and flink-streaming-java maven dependencies have build jdk 1.8. This is true for all 32 libraries I am using in my project. This is causing multiple incompatibilities in flink jobs when deployed on flink jobmanager.
Can anyone help me find the answer to the question: 'Why would flink team update java version on server side but not on client side knowing that this could result in incompatibilities?'
Or am I doing something wrong here?
Tried using latest version of flink maven dependencies. Found jdk version 1.8
Expected java version to be 17 on 1.18.1 version. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15736
Expected java version to be 21 on 1.19.0 version.

This shouldn't be the case. I have multiple Flink jobs that are targeting 1.18.1 while they all still run on, in my case, Java 11. When you are building these are you using a custom Dockerfile? If so, as long as your Flink image reflected the same version that you are using, you should be fine.

I had flink jobs on jdk 11 as well, but flink-core and other dependencies had 1.14.x version. Migrating to 1.18.1 and changing java version to 17 (along with other related changes), i saw errors with incompatibilities. On seeing the MANIFEST.MF file for all flink modules i see build jdk version is 1.8.
